# add line to a txt or csv file without introducing a new line on the file in shell script

Tags: linux

I have a txt/csv file and I want to add some text at the very end of the text that already exist in the txt/csv file. I have tried `echo -n "my txt" >> foo.csv`, also tried with `-ne` and `-e` flags but it is always writing the "my text" in a new line of the existing file.

Can anyone help?

*I can not use `cat` or `sed`* as those are not installed in the machine and I am not a root.

Suggestions regarding `echo` are preferred.

Comment: Since you need to remove a existing line break you need to filter it. You could probably read the whole file with `while read a; do echo $a; done >> outfile` and add some if condition to concatenate on the last round

Answer (score 0):

With `vim` / `ex`:

```
ex -sc 's/$/mytext/|w|q' test.txt
```